# How to invalidate Couchbase cache after update document

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am using Couchbase as a cache for my spring boot application.
but after updating my document i should wait for cache to expire in order to be refreshed. so basically deleting or updating any document dont invalidate it.

Here is my spring data repository :

```
public interface ConfigurationRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Configuration, String> {

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter}")
    @Cacheable(value = "Configuration_", unless = "#result == null")
    Optional<Configuration> getConfiguration();
}
```

my configuration :

```
spring.cache.cache-names=Configuration_
spring.cache.couchbase.expiration=10s
```

My document :

```
public class Configuration implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    public List<ConfigElement> properties;

    @Version
    private long version;
}
```

my dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchbase-spring-cache</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

could you please suggest a way to invalidate cache after updating document in the bucket ?

Comment: put `CacheEvict` in your update method

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-evict See this for more

Comment: thanks @gtiwari333 i will give it a try and tell you the result

Comment: thanks @gtiwari333 your proposition did the job, you can answer and i will validate and vote up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use @CacheEvict to evict the previously cached items when they are changed or deleted.

```
@CacheEvict(cacheNames="books", allEntries=true) 
public void loadBooks(InputStream batch)
```

> This process is useful for removing stale or unused data from the
> cache. As opposed to @Cacheable, @CacheEvict demarcates methods that
> perform cache eviction (that is, methods that act as triggers for
> removing data from the cache).

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-evict for more details